# Event called on pressing menu button in nokia touch device

Tags: java-me, nokia

I made a J2ME application(2D game) for nokia touch device like C7, N8 etc.
When I press the menu button while the gameplay is on, I reach the home screen on the device, but in the background, the game music still plays.
Can anyone tell me which event is called on pressing the menu button, and any possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Canvas.hideNotify()` is called when the midlet goes to background see [this article](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-574FCC00-89F1-4A21-BE03-3BB5D4151DE3.html?resultof=%22background%22%20) as well

Comment: thanks Gorkem, it was helful indeed. The article solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Call `player.stopPlayer()` in `hideNotify()` method of canvas. Probably gameCanvas of your application.

You can restart the music in `showNotify()` of your gameCanvas.